# Insert div after h2 in content

Tags: the-content

I'm trying to insert a div with a small bit of content immediately after the /h2 of single posts. I've given single posts a new class to help trigger this, as I don't want it after the /h2 on a page. I think I need to filter the content but am not sure how to write this function. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you can do that with a filter (`the_content`). I attached an example. You can put that into the `functions.php` of your theme.

```
function add_content_after_h2($content){
    if (is_single()) {
        $div = '<div>small bit of content</div>';
        $content = preg_replace('/(<\/h2>)/i', '\1'.$div, $content);
    }

    return $content;
}

add_filter('the_content', 'add_content_after_h2');
```

Here you find the Wordpress Codex with a detailed description of that filter:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content